# tailwindcss config with django

Tags: css, django, configuration, tailwind-css

I can't figure out how to config tailwindcss with django. I might just be doing the tailwind side wrong but I know I've configured my django static files correctly. I've watched every video I can find and none of them address my specific problem. An explanation of how tailwind config works on a low level would also be helpful so I could diagnose the problem myself. thanks.  [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2YRb.png) [file structure and config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6wvh.png)

Answer (score 1):

I will show how it is implemented for me and works with optimization.
Create frontend dir in in the root directory of the project:

```
├── backend
│   ├── backend
│   │   ├── asgi.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── wsgi.py
│   └── manage.py
├── frontend
└── venv
```

install tailwind [(see docs)](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/using-postcss)

```
cd frontend
npm install -D tailwindcss postcss postcss-cli autoprefixer cssnano
```

configurate tailwind:

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "postcss app/css/main.css -o app/css/main.min.css"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.8",
    "postcss": "^8.4.16",
    "postcss-cli": "^10.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8"
  }
}
```

create **postcss.config.js**:

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: {
      tailwindcss: {},
      autoprefixer: {},
      cssnano:{     # optimizes for production
          preset: 'default'
      },
    }
  }
```

create **tailwind.config.js**:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  darkMode: 'class',
  content: ["../backend/*/templates/*.{html, js}", "../backend/*/templates/components/*.{html, js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: []
  
}
```

create a **css** folder:

```
mkdir app
cd app
mkdir css
cd css
```

Inside css folder create **main.css** and cofigurate in:

**main.css**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Now will back and run the script:

```
cd ../../
npm run bild
```

This will create a **minified css** file in your **css folder** (`main.min.css`)

And configurate **settings.py**:

```
CORE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent
FRONT_DIR = CORE_DIR / 'frontend'

STATICFILES_DIRS = FRONT_DIR / 'app/'
```

Now to call static use in your template:
**base.html**

```
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.min.css' %}">
```

The use of cssnano is recommended by the tailwind. Purge not supported in new versions. [see docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrade-guide)

Answer (score 0):

Config tailwind css in django:

For this we have to make a file inside the static with the name jstools and navigate to this folder and inside the jstools by using the command in the terminal.

```
cd jstools
```

After this, we need to run some commands to add tailwind CSS.

```
npm init -y
```

After this, run the second command.

```
npm install tailwindcss autoprefixer clean-css-cli
```

next step: run below command

```
npx tailwindcss init -p
```

After this command, you can see some JSON and js files inside the js tool.

Now go inside the package.json and replace the code inside the data with this

```
code.
"build": "tailwind build ../static/css/tailwind.css -o ../static/css/style.css && cleancss -o ../static/css/style.min.css ../static/css/style.css"
```

And after this, go to inside the tailwind.config.js.

And change the module exports with this:

```
future: {
        removeDeprecatedGapUtilities: true,
        purgeLayersByDefault: true,
    },
    purge: {
        enabled: false, //true for production build
        content: ['../**/templates/*.html', '../**/templates/**/*.html']
    },
    theme: {
        extend: {},
    },
    variants: {},
    plugins: [],
```

Now go to inside the CSS folder of static and make a new file with the name tailwind.css.

And inside the tailwind.css write this code:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Now we have to go inside the jstools using terminal and run this command in terminal:

```
-npm run build
```

And now we just have to load the static inside the HTML page.

And we are ready to run tailwind CSS.

Comment: Thanks for the help. when i run npm run build its telling me that tailwind css doesn't exist when it does. can you think of any reason that might be happening?

Comment: just show me the error

Comment: figured it out thank you for this i've been trying to set this shit up for weeks

Comment: Is it solved your problem